# Using arrow keys to navigate between suggestions like Google

Tags: php, jquery

When user presses `Down` arrow key, I hope that it will selected the next suggestion.

When user presses `Up` arrow key, I hope that it will selected the previous suggestion.

For example, after you enter a search term, you can use the arrow keys to select the suggestions like Google.

How can I do this?

This is my current code:

script_suggestion.php:

```
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //document.getElementById("suggestion")

        function getSuggestion(q) {
            window.document.onkeyup = function (e)
            {
               if (!e) e = event;
               if (e.keyCode == 27)
               document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }

            var ajax;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)//for ie7+, FF, Chrome
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();//ajax object
            else
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for ie6 and previous
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(ajax.status === 200 && ajax.readyState === 4) {
                    //if result are not there then don't display them
                    if(ajax.responseText === "")
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    }
                }
            };
            ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=" + q, false);
            ajax.send();
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery-UI Autocomplete, it's everything you need. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: I have already read that but I still can't get what I want. Can you help me?

Comment: Is the demo on that site what you want?

Comment: I just want the arrow keys to work when selecting suggestions.

Comment: Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that using jQuery UI auto complete plugin (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Eg.

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lang").autocomplete({

            source: function(request, response) {
            $.get('suggest.php', { sqry: request.term }, function(data) {
                response(data.split("\n"));
            });
            }
       });
       });
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            Language : <input id="lang" name="lang">

        </body>
    </html>
```

suggest.php

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['sqry'])){
        $arrayVal = array();

        try {
            $connxn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$config['host'].";dbname=".$config['database'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
            $connxn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmnt = $connxn->prepare('select DISTINCT fieldName from tableName WHERE fieldName LIKE :sqry ORDER BY fieldName ASC LIMIT 0,25');

            $stmnt->execute(array('sqry' => '%'.$_GET['sqry'].'%'));

            while($row = $stmnt->fetch()) {

                      $arrayVal[] = $row['fieldName'];

            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

       echo implode("\n",$arrayVal);
    }

    ?>
```